# Cast comma-separated string to multiple 'in' clause values

Tags: amazon-aurora, mysql-8.0

```
set @ids = '1,2,3';
delete from mytable where id in (@ids);
```

The sql statement above gives this error:

> Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '1,2,3'

How can I cast @ids, or write the query in another way, so that it deletes the three records from mytable?

Sql mode is set to
"IGNORE_SPACE,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES"

Comment: CSV strings aren't simple is SQL. See, for example, https://www.sisense.com/blog/splitting-comma-separated-values-in-mysql/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In end I went with a prepared statement.

```
set @ids = '1,2,3';
set @query = concat('delete from mytable where id in (',@ids,');');
PREPARE sql_query from @query;
EXECUTE sql_query;
```